# primaryTogglesNestedList not working properly

Tags: reactjs, material-ui

I'm fairly new to the react and as the title states, I've set-up a nested list using `material-ui (SelectableList)` here. But so far I'm trying to figure out why the nested list won't toggle so I am using `primaryTogglesNestedList={true}` it toggle my nested list but when `primaryTogglesNestedList` is true then `nestedList` item `onclick (Link)` is not working it means not redirect to the targeted page code is below.

I think I'm missing a dependency or something, please help.

```
<ListItem 
    value={itemJSON.name}
    innerDivStyle={styles.listStyle}
    hoverColor={'#eff2f6'}
    nestedListStyle={styles.nestedItems}
    primaryText={primaryText}
    primaryTogglesNestedList={true}
    nestedItems={this._toNestedItems(itemJSON.items)} />
```

Comment: can you show the `link` part , `_toNestedItems` function ?

Comment: _toNestedItems(nestedItems) {
  let listItems = []
  let thisRef=this;
  let _toListItemFn = this._toListItem
  
  if (nestedItems) {
   nestedItems.map(function(nestedItemJSON){  
    listItems.push(_toListItemFn(nestedItemJSON,thisRef))
   })
  } 
   
  return listItems
 }

Comment: can you update the ques with complete code, place where you are using `link` ?